# try to getting country code but without alert its not work

Tags: javascript, xpath

this is my code:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
            $.get(
        "final.xml",
        null,
        function (data) {
            xml = data;
        },
        "xml"
    );
    function get_list(){
             var city = $('#name').val();
            var xPath = '//*[@value = "' + city + '"]/../../@value';

          var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            var str = '';
            while (thisNode) {
                if (str) {
                    str += ', ';
                }
                str += thisNode.textContent;
                thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            }

            $.get(
                "country_code.xml",
                null,
                function (data) {
                    xml = data;
                },
                "xml"
            );
             var code = str;
            var xPath1 = '//*[@name = "' + code + '"]/@code';
          var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath1, xml.documentElement, null,
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            var str1 = '';
            while (thisNode) {
                if (str1) {
                    str1 += ', ';
                }
                str1 += thisNode.textContent;
                thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            }
            $("#result").text(str1);
        }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" ></input>
<input type="button"  name = "Get Code" onclick="get_list()"></input>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here i have two xml file in first xml file i am try to getting country name using textbox entered city name and store it on var `str` in my second xml file i am try to find the country code using this var `str`.

its not give any error but not give any result when i am try to alert before my second xpath then its work i am try to alert before second xpath this `alert(str);`
please help me out of this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that `$.get` is asynchronous, meaning it won't block execution and wait for the request (the fetching of the xml file) to complete.

In `get_list` function you are initiating the request (calling `$.get`), then 3 lines later using the xml variable (`xml.evaluate(...)`). Because `$.get` doesn't block, the request may not have returned, your callback that assigns `xml = data` will not have run and therefor `xml` will not be defined.

The reason the alert "fixes" it is because alert *does* block, which gives the extra time needed for the response to come back.

The solution is to either force `$.get` to run synchronously by passing the `async = false` option to the call (as [documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)), or by ensuring all of the code that makes use of the returned data is only executed *after* the call has returned (usually by running it from the callback, though there are other ways (promises for example)).

Note: Forcing synchronous is usually not the right answer, they are async by default for a reason.